# integral formula for conditional expectation with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be real random variables with joint density $f$ and let $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable with $\mathbf{E}[|h(X)|]<\infty$. Denote by $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Show that almost surely
$$
\mathbf{E}[h(X) \mid Y]=\frac{\int h(x) f(x, Y) \lambda(d x)}{\int f(x, Y) \lambda(d x)} .
$$

This is Exercise 8.2.9(i) of Probability Theory by Klenke. Based on definition 8.11, I know that

$\mathbf{E}[h(X) \mid Y] = \mathbf{E}[h(X) \mid \sigma(Y)]$

Comment: What have you tried? This follows by simply plugging in definitions

Comment: You say it follows from "definitions." Does it follow from the ones in section 8.1, 8.2 of Probability Theory by Klenke?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show that the right side is measurable w.r.t. $\sigma (Y)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mu$ denote the probability measure on the domain of the random variables. Based on the definition of conditional expectation, $E[h(X) \mid Y]$ is the unique $\sigma(Y)-$measurable function such that $$\int_{Y \in A} h(X) d \mu = \int_{Y \in A} \mathbb{E}[h(X) \mid Y] d \mu$$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),$ where uniqueness in understood in the usual measure theoretical way. Thus it suffices to show that $\frac{\int h(x) f(x, Y) \lambda(d x)}{\int f(x, Y) \lambda(d x)}$ also satisfies this equality for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).$ We have that

$$\int_{Y \in A} \frac{\int h(x) f(x, Y) d\lambda(x)}{\int f(x, Y) d\lambda( x)} d \mu = \int_A \frac{\int h(x) f(x, y) d\lambda(x)}{\int f(x, y) d\lambda(x)} f_Y(y) d\lambda(y) = \\ \int_A \frac{\int h(x) f(x, y) d\lambda(x)}{\int f(x, y) d\lambda(x)} \int f(x, y) d \lambda(x) d \lambda(y) = \\ \int_A\int h(x) f(x, y) d \lambda(x) \lambda(y) = \iint h(x) \chi_A(y) f(x, y) d\lambda(x) d\lambda(y) = \\ \int h(X) \chi_A(Y) d \mu = \int_{Y \in A} h(X) d \mu.$$ Note that in the first equality I used the [change of variables formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure). I hope this helps. :)